# Failed asset loading iOS 8/9 (PhoneGap app) with F5 load balanced servers

Tags: ios, cordova, f5, big-ip

I have a strange situation that has been plaguing me for a few weeks now.  I have a PhoneGap app that utilizes a few plugins (annotations and email), beyond that, the native app is just a simple HTML file with a JavaScript location redirect:

```
<script>
    document.location.href='https://our.server.com/appdir';
</script>
```

The user community of the app are on iPads, iOS 8.x-9.x (iOS users on 7.x have no issues).  There is a F5 load balancer that directs traffic between 2 servers.  We are having an issue where some users are not getting all assets downloaded (i.e. a stylesheet will be missing).

This is predominantly only an issue within the PhoneGap app and when the F5 load balancer is utilized (iPad app has been build with both the UIWebView and WKWebView and both exhibit the same issue.  We previously had an A10 load balancer and there were no issues.  We have since tested using an A10 load balancer pointing to the same servers, and there are no issues.  The F5 guys are scratching their heads.

The applications generally works fine in safari (obviously the plugins don't work though), and on desktop browsers.  The rare occasions that we've seen errors in safari, the error is "network connection lost".

To further muddy the waters, some users have no issues.  My iPad has no issues at all.  The assets always come down as expected.  I cannot identify any difference between my iPad and a user who is experiencing the issue.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

Comment: Are you using any caching on the F5 BIG-IP?  If caching was involved, the BIG-IP may see your connections as generic HTTP views and assume it's a browser.  It would then tell the browser to use previously requested elements instead of allowing a re-request.

Also, who at F5 are you working with and did you post this also to devcentral.f5.com?

Comment: Follow up comment:  I did have similar behavior once with a script because the source persistence of traffic caused the script to confuse the varying connections and return results to the wrong session.  I removed the javascript mime type from my http profile in BIG-IP and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks Chaseabbott!  We are working with the F5 escalation team.  I'm not personally engaging them as I'm the owner of the app, not the servers/load balancers.  Tonight a fix is being put in to address the compression settings.  It seems that not all of the required parameters were set up in the http profile.  We are testing that fix tonight and I will post back.  I shared your comments with the network folks and will update this thread with the results as we move forward.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The good thing about BIG-IP are tons of features.... the bad thing about BIG-IP... tons of features.  ;-)

Comment: Did this get worked out?  If so, can you post the answer?  Just want to make sure this wasn't left open ended.

Comment: Thanks for following up Chaseabbott.  We do not have a definitive answer from F5 escalation team.  Likely they will say we need to upgrade from our current version of F5 (10.2.4) to 11.5 or 11.6.  For now, we have migrated all our mobile applications to an A10 load balancer that works as expected.  If/when we ever get the F5 issue resolved, I will post the results.

Comment: If you want, lemme know who your team was working with and I can follow up.  It should work with no issues but if they're new to the device I am hoping the learning curve isn't throwing them for a loop.  Alternatively, whomever is configuring it should head over to DevCentral.f5.com and ask F5's community for assistance... just in case.  Cheers!